# App loading wrong colours after application update

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a really weird problem with resources loading (colours) in my Android application.
At the beginning some introduction about the environment:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId appPackageName
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode verCode
    versionName verName

    multiDexEnabled  true
    ...
}
```

I have an application with code version 40, and after fresh install everything is OK. After few commits, I've prepared build with code version set to 41. This build also works without any problems. The weird things begin when I made application update from 40 to 41. After this operation in one place in the application I noticed, that colours loaded from resources are incorrect.

Here is the line how I'm setting text colour (ArrayAdapter):

```
holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, value.getColor()));
```

I've done some investigation and found, that after application update I get wrong colour identifiers (placed in R.java file) for the same resource:

Fresh installation 41 (OK):

```
7F06007F => public static final int my_text_font_color=0x7f06007f;
```

Update from 40 to 41 (WRONG):

```
7F060082 => public static final int my_window_color=0x7f060082;
```

Any ideas or hint how can I fix this problem?

**Edit (more information)**

Generally *value* is instance of Realm object which has the property set to colour resource id:

```
public Integer getColor() {
    return color;
}
```

Here is example how this color is set:

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new Setting(context.getString(R.string.status_pending), "pending", R.color. my_text_font_color));
```

Comment: What is the `value.getColor()` why not `R.color.someColor`?

Comment: @Yupi I've added more information to my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are storing color id which is auto-generated by Android Studio in `R.java` class. Whenever you add views, strings, etc in your resource, the R.java is updated with the new set of id.

[ContextCompat.getColor(Context context, int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)) is returning the value of the color from color id which is probably is different id whenever you update your resource files:

> [getColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int))(Context context, int id)
> Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID
>
> Starting in M, the returned color will be styled for the specified Context's theme.

When you call the following code:

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new Setting(context.getString(R.string.status_pending), "pending", R.color. my_text_font_color));
```

You're saving the **color resource id** not the color value.

So, you need to either save the color value or save the name of the color resource.